# Is it possible to romance Jack in Mass Effect 2 without re-playing Mass Effect 1?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm trying to romance Jack in Mass Effect 2, but I don't want to replay the first Mass Effect and when I chose the "new game" option it chooses for the default romance option of Kaidan.

How do I romance Jack without replaying Mass Effect?

Comment: IIRC you are given an option to set the "Kaiden or Ashley" choice when starting a new game of ME2. But it shouldnt be 'this character or that character'. It should not have an effect on whether you can romance jack

Comment: Isn't the choice between Liara and your opposite gender? At least in unmodded Mass Effect, if you romanced Kaiden, you're  batting for the wrong team for Jack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who you romanced in Mass Effect 1 has no impact on romancing Jack, who you don't meet until Mass Effect 2 anyway. All that matters is that you don't romance somebody else while you're romancing Jack, as she has very low self esteem and doesn't handle it very well at all.

When completing her loyalty mission ensure you review all of the available logs and talk to Jack afterwards to get her feelings on what you've learned. It's best to choose the caring dialogue option whenever one presents itself to you while taking with Jack.

Later in the game after completing both Jack and Miranda's loyalty mission you will come back aboard the Normandy to find them fighting with each other. You must either side with Jack or use your Paragon/Renegade dialogue option to break up the fight if you want to keep Jack happy.

Comment: Also, IIRC, she offers to sleep with you early on. Doing so shuts down any chance at romance.

Answer (score -1):

impossible to romance jack as a girl

Comment: -1 *Poor Answer* | Could you elaborate?